# How to access a database postgres table with a foreign key from django model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I would like simply just to access a database table, which contains a foreign key.
I have 2 tables created within postgres 9.1.

The models within Django are:

```
class bfirma(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table="bfirma"

f_id= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
f_name = models.TextField()
```

.

```
class bworker(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table="bworker"

w_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
w_name = models.TextField()
fk_f_id=models.ForeignKey(bfirma)
```

This is how it looks in the table:

```
bfirma(table)
f_id(pk)|f_name
1        BMW
2        Benz

bworker(table)
w_id(pk)|w_name|fk_f_id(fk)
1        WorkerA 1
2        WorkerB 1
3        WorkerC 2
```

Calling the model **bfirma** without the FOREIGN KEY is working fine. No problems. But i can not call the model **bworker**

```
bf= bfirma.objects.using(db).filter(f_name='BMW').values()  WORKING FINE
bw = bworker.objects.using(db).all().values() ERROR:= Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet'>
```

If i comment out the following line with the FOREIGN KEY definition, it works

```
#fk_f_name=models.ForeignKey(bfirma)
```

I would just like to have something really really easy: name of bfirma and bworker

```
select bfirma.f_name, bworker.w_name from bfirma, bworker
where bfirma.f_id = bworker.fk_f_id
```

**Update:** Yesterday my PC just froze; i had to retart. After that i created a new database and suddanly it WORKED. Somehow it can now handle the line with the ForeignKey...

Comment: Offtopic: please name your classes (including models) in CamelCase and try to use readable names for all variables.

Comment: And check the code you posted - in your code bw can not throw error about ValuesQuerySet because it does not use values().

Comment: Try to start without values(): [(bw.w_name, bw.bfirma.f_name) for bw in bworker.objects.using(db).all()]

Comment: i updated the post. and yes, i will try it with .all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would just like to have something really really easy: name of bfirma
>   and bworker

```
bw = bworker.objects.get(pk=1) # fetch bworker with primary key 1
print bw.fk_f_id.f_name # f_name of bfirma for this bworker
```

Comment: `bw = bworder.objects.select_related().get(pk=1)`